# SPARQL strlen showing incorrect value for xs:date

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

### Scenario

I'm using the open source dbpedia browser to get a handle on sparql queries.  I'm attempting to parse both the month and day values out of an xs:date for dbo:birthDate.  It is not a dateTime so I cannot use month() or dayOfWeek() functions.  I've instead gone with substr which works perfectly fine for month.  However, trying to substring with values 9,2 give me an invalid index error.  So I modified the sparql to show the string and the strlen values and now I'm totally confused.  The string it shows is a valid date format "yyyy-mm-dd" which is 10 characters.  However, it shows a strlen of 7.

Here is the query:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?name, ?bmonth, ?bstring, ?len1, ?len2
WHERE {
  ?person foaf:name ?name .
  ?person dbo:birthDate ?birth .
  BIND (str(?birth) AS ?bstring)
  BIND (strlen(?bstring) AS ?len1)
  BIND (substr(?bstring, 6,2) AS ?bmonth)
  BIND (strlen(?bstring) AS ?len2)
  FILTER ( ?bmonth = '12' )
} GROUP BY ?person ORDER BY ?len1 LIMIT 50
```

And here are a few rows of the results:

```
name            bmonth  bstring        len1 len2
"Ann Ronell"@e  "12"    "1906-12-28"    7   7
"Anna Freud"@en "12"    "1895-12-03"    7   7
"Dorothy Lamour"@en "12"    "1914-12-10"    7   7
"Doug Mohns"@en "12"    "1933-12-13"    7   7
```

Query: http://tinyurl.com/k6kuapd

### Conclusion/Question

Essentially, I'm really just trying to get the dayOfMonth value from the string.  But if anyone could also explain to me how it's coming up with 7 I'd truly appreciate it!

Comment: Part of the problem here is your use of GROUP BY, apparently to eliminate duplicate solutions for each person. Technically this is an invalid query - if you have a GROUP BY, the only thing you can have in your SELECT is a grouped variable or an aggregate expression. If the query actually runs, its results are undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Extracting the day and month by casting to xsd:dateTime

SPARQL 1.1 has a `day` function that returns the day of a dateTime.

> #### [17.4.5.4 day](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-day)
>
> ```
> xsd:integer  DAY (xsd:dateTime arg)
> ```
>
> Returns the day part of arg as an integer.
>
> This function corresponds to [fn:day-from-dateTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-day-from-dateTime).
>
> ```
> day("2011-01-10T14:45:13.815-05:00"^^xsd:dateTime)
> => 10
> ```

You can use `xsd:dateTime` as a function to convert `xsd:date`s into `dateTimes` to which you can apply this function.  As an example:

```
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select ?month ?day where {
  # Provide some values for ?date.  Note that 
  # we can use xsd:date *and* xsd:dateTime here,
  # as both can be cast to xsd:dateTime.
  values ?date { 
    "2011-01-02"^^xsd:date
    "2012-10-11"^^xsd:date
    "2013-12-30T14:45:13.815-05:00"^^xsd:dateTime 
  }

  # Cast to a xsd:dateTime and extract the day and month.
  bind( day(xsd:dateTime(?date)) as ?day )
  bind( month(xsd:dateTime(?date)) as ?month )
}
```

```
---------------
| month | day |
===============
| 01    | 02  |
| 10    | 11  |
| 12    | 30  |
---------------
```

### Why DBpedia does strange things

The easiest way to find out why you get seven as the length sometimes is to ask for values where the length *is* seven and see what you get.  E.g., look at the results of

```
SELECT ?person ?birth WHERE {
  ?person dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birth .
  bind( strlen(str(?birth)) as ?blen )
  filter( ?blen < 10 )
}
LIMIT 25
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20?person%20?birth%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?person%20dbpedia-owl%3abirthDate%20?birth%20.%0D%0A%20%20bind%28%20strlen%28str%28?birth%29%29%20as%20?blen%20%29%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20?blen%20%3C%2010%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2025&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
Person                            Birth
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Alyson_No%C3%ABl                  "--12-03"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gMonthDay>
Corneille_(singer)                "--03-24"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gMonthDay>
Count_Karl_Sigmund_von_Hohenwart  "--02-12"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gMonthDay>
David_Lewis_(politician)          "--06-23"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#gMonthDay>
…                                 …
```

There are values that aren't `xsd:dateTimes` or `xsd:date`s, but rather `xsd:gMonthDay`s.  These don't have a year specified, so the the strings aren't as long as those for `xsd:date`s.  This is another reason that shows why you should cast to `xsd:date`s (or check the datatype, etc., since you can't cast from an `xsd:gMonthDay` to a `xsd:dateTime`).

As was pointed out in the comments, your query isn't actually legal.  You shouldn't be able to select non-grouped variables, so *perhaps* what's happening is that when you've done

```
SELECT ?name, ?bmonth, ?bstring, ?len1, ?len2 WHERE {
  ?person foaf:name ?name .
  ?person dbo:birthDate ?birth .
  BIND (str(?birth) AS ?bstring)
  BIND (strlen(?bstring) AS ?len1)
  BIND (substr(?bstring, 6,2) AS ?bmonth)
  BIND (strlen(?bstring) AS ?len2)
  FILTER ( ?bmonth = '12' )
}
GROUP BY ?person
ORDER BY ?len1
LIMIT 50
```

you're getting some DBpedia specific behavior.  E.g., perhaps you're grouping by the person, and then the select is doing an implicit `sample` and maybe some of these persons have multiple values for their birth date.  (I'm not certain about this, it's just a possibility that occurs to me.  DBpedia is doing maintainence at the moment, so I can't check what data's there, and even if I could, this is behavior not defined by the standard.  I suggest that you check your queries at [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html) and get legal SPARQL first.  Only then can we tell if you if it's returning what it ought to.)

Comment: It looks like DBPedia's SPARQL engine doesn't even need the cast to dateTime - its month and day functions also work on xsd:date literals.

Comment: O, that might be a standard conversion;  I'm not sure, but I'll check the spec.  If it is, then this can be a little simpler.

Comment: Not standard as far as I can tell - http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/#built-in-datatypes says xsd:date and xsd:dateTime both derive from xsd:anySimpleType. Also, I had to add a regex filter to stop DBPedia's engine from choking on malformed literals in the day and month functions.

Comment: @Alex Right, but the day function is described as corresponding to `fn:day-from-dateTime($arg as xs:dateTime?) as xs:integer?`.  Does the `$arg as xs:dateTime` mean that there's an automatic (attempted) cast?

Comment: I don't think the spec requires any sort of automatic casting for anything other than numeric types, but allows implementations to do so when it makes sense.

Comment: @Alex So the `as` just indicates the expected type, not an automatic cast?  I haven't spent much time in the XSD specs, so I'm not sure yet…

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the links.  I will certainly check them out and fix my query.  I indeed used group by to avoid duplicates, is there a better way to ensure distinct matches?  And the theory on why it shows 7 makes sense to me, at least more so than showing me a 10 character string and telling me its 7!  Since I am only after month and day anyway I am wondering if I can cast it always to gMonthDay anyway? I'll play around some more.  Thanks!

Comment: @Alex, I tried a regex filter to avoid these cases, and tried a coalesce() to catch them. Neither way worked for me (still failed on the typecast afterward); any chance you can post your example? Thanks!